# SSRS 2008 R2 using two iif statements

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-excel

In an existing SSRS 2008 r2 report, I have the following `IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Gainsboro", "White")` for the background color for every other detail line row.
Basically one detail line is white and the next detail line is a light green color.

Now the user wants every other detail line to remain white and light green color when displayed on the report server. However when the report is to be exported to excel,
the user wants all lines exported to excel to be completely white.

Here are the steps the user will complete:
   The user will select ‘Hide’ from the ‘Excel Export_Hide Headers’ dropdown list. 
   The user will next select the view button prior to exporting the report to excel.
   The user will then select the export to excel option.
**The user is basically going to hide the header rows when the report is suppose to be exported to excel.
.
When the header rows are are being hidden, the following logic is being used: `iif(Parameters!ExcelToolbar.Value = 0,false,true)`.

Thus can you tell me how to tie the `iif(Parameters!ExcelToolbar.Value = 0,false,true)`, with the `IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Gainsboro", "White")` statement?

Would this be nested iif statements? If so, can you tell show me how to setup the applicable nested iif statements? If this is not the solution, would you show me in code, explain to me, and/or point me to a url that will solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Nested if statements should work, or you could write a function that takes a boolean in the code portion of the report and call that function.

For the nested iif statments, it should be something like this, checking to decide to use Gainsboro or white based on the toolbar setting.

```
IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, IIF(Parameters!ExcelToolbar.Value = 0,"Gainsboro","White"), "White")
```

It is also recommended to use a switch statment if you are going to nest 3 or more(mentioned in the decision functions portion): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Comment: I have not used a switch statement. Thus can you tell me how to use the switch statement in this case?

Comment: Not sure switch is the best idea here, but it would be something like this.  This is assuming you want white every time when Exceltoolbar.value is 0.  `=Switch(Parameters!ExcelToolbar.Value = 0, "White",RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0,"Gainsboro",True,"White")`